# while installing python2.6 getting error on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python

"I am using ubuntu 12.04 and by default python 2.7 is installed .I want python 2.6 .
When I used 
apt-get install python2.6
I am getting error 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python2.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python-gdbm

E: Package 'python2.6' has no installation candidate

Thanks in advance."

Comment: This is a question for http://askubuntu.com/ .  You need either a backported package or, if that is not available, to install from source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [Ubuntu Wiki - Python Toolchain](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Python_Toolchain), Python 2.6 is no longer available in the repository.

Either:

- You can simply build it from source by downloading the tarball from
  [Python 2.6.7](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.6.7/)
- You need to find out some repository which might have an older version of
  Python. One alternative is
  https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes

You need to install the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
```

Run Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the version you are looking for

```
sudo apt-get install python2.6 python2.6-dev
```